# Computer won't boot except by efi file

Tags: boot, uefi

I'm here today because I have a lot of trouble with my computer under Ubuntu.

I decided to re-install my computer 2 days ago. And, don't know why, I must pass throught the boot option in my bios and chose "boot from efi file" and chose the grub efi file to correctly boot.

Can someone help me?

Edit : output of efibootmgr -v

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002
Boot0000* Notebook Upgrade Bay  BIOS(3,0,00).......................................................................
Boot0001* Notebook Hard Drive   BIOS(2,0,00).......................................................................
Boot0002* Notebook Ethernet BIOS(80,0,00)........................A..............................................
Boot0003* Notebook Ethernet  BIOS(80,0,00)........................A..............................................
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,800,100000,3a68052e-6a3c-4654-a7ac-4e600b5f2292)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of the following command: `sudo efibootmgr -v`. Be sure to add four spaces to the start of each line of that output to keep it legible. (Four spaces at the start of a line is a formatting code for text-mode program output rather than a natural-language paragraph.) The `efibootmgr` output will show us how your system is configured to boot, which may suggest a solution. To the person who voted to close this question as unclear, it *is* a clear question if you understand EFI-mode booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your `boot` directory, it should be like this:

`/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/` ----> `BOOTx64.EFI`

if the file isn't there, you can issue the following command:

`sudo cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/boot/BOOTx64.EFI`

assuming `boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` exists. if not, copy it from wherever you can find it inside `EFI` directory and its sub directories.